# Working list-group bootstrap

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Now I'm having trouble finding out how to get a `list-group` working. I want a panel on the left side, using `col-lg-9`. On the right side there's a selection menu, using `col-lg-3`.

I wan't this selection menu to dynamically change the content of the page. So when I click on item 1, the panel provides info that is meant to be for item 1.

So far I've come to this, but this doesn't work yet.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class='container'>
  <div class='row'>
    <div class='col-lg-9'>
      <div class='panel panel-default' id='panel1'>
        <div class='panel-body'>
          <div class='page-header'>
            <h3>The first panel <small>Posted on december 23 2015</small></h3>
          </div>
          <img class='featuredImg' src='resources/screenshot1.png'>
          <p>Another paragraph</p>
          <h4>This is a header</h4>
          <p>Paragraph to match this header</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class='panel panel-default' id='panel2'>
        <div class='panel-body'>
          <div class='page-header'>
            <h3>This is panel two <small>Posted on december 24 2015</small></h3>
          </div>
          <p>This is a paragraph for panel two</p>
          <h4>This is a sub header for panel two</h4>
          <p>This is content belonging to subheading of panel two</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class='col-lg-3'>
      <div class='list-group'>
        <a href='#panel1' class='list-group-item active' data-toggle='tab'>
          <h4 class='list-group-item-heading'>Item 1</h4>
          <p class='list-group-item-text'>Short info about the item</p>
        </a>
        <a href='#panel2' class='list-group-item' data-toggle='tab'>
          <h4 class='list-group-item-heading'>Item 2</h4>
          <p class='list-group-item-text'>Short info about the item</p>
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Why you not using jQuery?

Comment: Do you have some javascript that goes with this?  You also seem to be using the classes for `list-group-item` on non-list elements.  http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_list_groups.asp

Comment: If you're modifying the DOM, you're going to need to use javascript (jQuery).

Comment: @AdamKonieska if you scroll down a little further, it says: To create a list group with linked items, use `<div>` instead of `<ul>` and `<a>` instead of `<li>`.

Comment: @DrewKennedy As you can see in the code I have given, I use the data-toggle and the href to get javascript to do some work. I've seen some similar examples, using somewhat the same code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you need to combine that `tabs` and the `item-list`  components.

Like this:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class='container'>
  <div class='row'>
    <div class='col-lg-9 tab-content'>
      <div class='panel panel-default tab-pane active' id='panel1'>
        <div class='panel-body'>
          <div class='page-header'>
            <h3>The first panel <small>Posted on december 23 2015</small></h3>
          </div>
          <img class='featuredImg' src='resources/screenshot1.png'>
          <p>Another paragraph</p>
          <h4>This is a header</h4>
          <p>Paragraph to match this header</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class='panel panel-default tab-pane' id='panel2'>
        <div class='panel-body'>
          <div class='page-header'>
            <h3>This is panel two <small>Posted on december 24 2015</small></h3>
          </div>
          <p>This is a paragraph for panel two</p>
          <h4>This is a sub header for panel two</h4>
          <p>This is content belonging to subheading of panel two</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class='col-lg-3'>
      <ul class='list-group'>
        <li class="list-group-item active">
          <a href='#panel1' data-toggle='tab'>
            <h4 class='list-group-item-heading'>Item 1</h4>
            <p class='list-group-item-text'>Short info about the item</p>
          </a>
        </li>
        <li class="list-group-item">
          <a href='#panel2' data-toggle='tab'>
            <h4 class='list-group-item-heading'>Item 2</h4>
            <p class='list-group-item-text'>Short info about the item</p>
          </a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: That fixed the tab part. Now all that is left to do is to make the list-group active class correspond with the content. Is there an easy fix for that too?

Comment: I don't understand. What the expected result?

Comment: I want list-item 1 to have the active class when the content of panel 1 is visible. When I click list-item 2, the active class gets removed from list-item 1 and added to list item 2. This is the js I have already, but that block the dynamic panel content. `<script>
            $('div.list-group a').click(function(e) {
            var $this = $(this);
            $('div.list-group').find('a.active').removeClass('active')
            $this.addClass('active');
            return false;
            });
        </script>`

Comment: I think that my demo already support this. When the content 1 is shown, the tab1 has class `.active` and he has blue background (because of the class `.active`. Didn't you see it?

Comment: Correct. The content changes, but not the active state of the `list-group-item`. List-group-item with the text "Item 1" is always active, while I want "Item 2" to be active when content two is shown. So the selectors aren't dynamic yet.

Comment: Do you mean in page load? Because when the page load with the tab1 shown it's looks like this: http://i.stack.imgur.com/7kFyN.png. Then, if you click on item2 it's looks like this:http://i.stack.imgur.com/M6UJd.png

Comment: Yes, that's what I want! But as far as I'm concerned, that's not what happens now

Comment: I don't understand. Those images are screenshots of my answer. Do you see something else? Or do you mean in your website?

Comment: Those images are not what's happening on my page.

Comment: Can you provide a public URL or any other way that I can see it in live?

Comment: I must have missed something when copying your code. I now tried it again, and it works fine. So thanks again!

Comment: No problem ;) My pleasure.. Good luck!